# If certain cells meet criteria, change targeted cell in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, criteria

If column A contains "RR" and column C is not equal to "memo" and column E is not equal to "Air" or "Printed" then column L=0.

Then followed by If column A contains "RR" and column C is not equal to "memo" and column E is equal to "Air" or "Printed" then column L= is column H*.1.

I believe I am having trouble with equals/not equals.

```
Sub RRClean()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim myString As String
RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To RowCount
    myString = Trim(Cells(i, 2).Value)
    If InStr(myString, "RR") > 0 And .cell(i, 3) <> "Memo" And .cell(i, 7) <> "Air" Or .cell(i, 7) <> "Printed" Then
        Cells(i, 12).Value = 0
    End If
Next

For i = 2 To RowCount
    myString = Trim(Cells(i, 2).Value)
    If InStr(myString, "RR") > 0 And .cell(i, 3) <> "Memo" And .cell(i, 7) = "Air" Or .cell(i, 7) = "Printed" Then
        Cells(i, 12).Value = cell(i, 8) * 0.1
    End If
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you switch between `cell` and `.cell` (you're missing s btw) but try adding `.value` after said `cells`.

Comment: 1) `cell` should be `Cells`.  2) putting the `.` before `Cells` without a `With` block will not work.  Put `With Activesheet` before your `RowCount = ...`. Then with every `Range` or `Cells` put the `.` before it.  Then after your final `next` put `End With`.

Comment: @findwindow it didn't work but thanks

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks worked like a charm

Comment: @ScottCraner is there a way i can upvote your comment?

Comment: If you hover on the left side of the comment you will see an up arrow.  Glad I could help.  Take the time to learn why this is needed and what putting the `.` before a function means

Comment: I actually don't see anything when I hover, is that an earned functionality as I am newer to this site. Yes I will definitely go over VBA basics over the weekend. Any recs on sites or resources?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is slightly flawed when dealing with *"and column E is not equal to "Air" or "Printed""*. If a cell is not *Air* it could be *Printed*. If it is not *Printed* then it could be *Air*. You need **And** here as in *"and column E is not equal to "Air" and column E is not equal to "Printed"*.

```
Sub Cmemo()
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")    '<~~ SET THIS WORKSHEET REFERENCE PROPERLY!!
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*RR*"
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>memo"
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>Air", _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Printed"
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0).Cells)) Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 11)
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = 0
                End With
            End If
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Air", _
                        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Printed"
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0).Cells)) Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 11)
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[-4]/10"
                End With
            End If
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Using the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx), both operations can be accomplished without declaring a single variable.

Comment: thanks for the post. I don't have time right now,but will definitely look at it tomorrow.

Comment: yeah i see what you are saying about the logic, but it has worked perfectly. cant tell you if the code you wrote works as ive been locked out for the weekend.

Comment: The logic works because you are performing the 0's first. In fact you are putting zero in all of the cells that match the first two criteria because the third criteria is a global match. Then you overwrite *some* of the 0's when the next round places formulas in some. It works, but cannot be relied upon. If you reversed the order and did the formulas first, they would all be overwritten with 0's.

Comment: just tested your code and it runs but doesnt work the way i mentioned. I cant find the rhyme or reason to your code.

Comment: none of the cells i need zeroed out are zeroed out, but the memos were untouched which is a good thing. and also the cells that i needed multiplied by .10 with the value of another cell were also unaccomplished.

Comment: Put Sheet4 (or whatever the worksheet is named) on the left side of the computer screen. Tap [Alt]+[F11] to open the VBE and position it on teh right side of the screen so you can see the **Cmemo** sub procedure as well as a good portion of the worksheet behind it on the left. Position the cursor anywhere within the sub procedure and tap [F8]. Keep tapping [F8] to walk through the procedure line-by-line. Watch the worksheet behind it on the left for visible changes and figure out what is happening or not happening.